# How to say that I hit a car (by accident)

Tags: idioms, spoken-english, phrase-usage

How does one say that one was in an accident with one’ car?
I am not sure if any of the following phrases are correct. Please tell me if the spoken forms below are correct, or if there are any other idioms or phrases used to express this idea.

- I hit a car in the street.
- I crashed a car in the street.
- I collided a car in the street.

Comment: It depends on what events you are describing. Each of your phrasings (including the ones in your description and title) suggests a different set of possible occurrences. The only one that doesn’t really work is “I collided a car in the street”. Collisions require two moving objects, so if one is you (or “you” abstracted to your vehicle) and one is a car, you would say “I collided **with** a(nother) car”. “Collision” can also be used as a noun, generally **between** one thing **and** another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is OK.

The second and third can be changed like this

> I crashed into a car in the street.
>
> I collided with a car in the street.

*do accident* should be *had an accident*

Comment: are they naturally used while speaking? mean,, the formal way?

Comment: @fSazy Yes, all three would be natural in speech and easily understood by the listener.

Comment: "I crashed a car in the street." sounds ambiguous and the "car" in this statement is understood to be one driven by the speaker, and the object into which the car crashed is left unknown. One might say "I crashed my car!"

Answer (score 3):

Informally, you can have a ***shunt*** or (esp. UK, ***prang***), but those *nouns* are usually only used of relatively minor ***collisions*** (not *fatal* accidents). The "idiomatic" versions of OP's suggested *verbs* (where another vehicle is involved) are...

> *I **hit** a car in the street.
>
>    I **crashed into** a car in the street.
>
>    I **collided with** a car in the street*.

Note that you can say *"I pranged **my** car"* (you hit something, or ran it into a ditch, say), but you don't usually *prang **into** another car*. And as a verb usage you don't *shunt* your own car - you might (rarely) *shunt **into** another vehicle*, but that usually implies the other car wasn't moving at the time - if two *moving* vehicles collide (usually, at relatively low speeds), they *have **a** shunt*.

More serious accidents include ***pile-ups*** or ***smash-ups*** (involving three or more vehicles), but they happen on things like motorways, not streets. If a vehicle is damaged beyond economic repair you might say you ***totalled*** it (where an insurance company would say it's a total write-off, and offer you the value of the car before the accident, rather than pay for it to be repaired). You wouldn't normally use that expression if fatalities were involved.

If you're in a line of (usually, relatively slow-moving) traffic in a street and one car stops suddenly (to avoid hitting a dog, say) several of the following cars may be unable to stop in time. In which case they're involved in a ***shunt collision*** (only the tailgate/boot of the first car and the front bumper/bonnet of the last are damaged, but all the others suffer *both* types of damage).

Comment: As a side note, _prang_ is not used much over here in the U.S. We might use _ding_ instead.

Comment: _ding_ is also used in Australia, I think.

Comment: @jimsug: I suppose things may be different in Australia, but in my understanding *ding = [relatively small] **dent***. I could *ding* my car by clumsy parking, but I probably wouldn't call that an *accident*.

Comment: @Fumble I suppose it would be _accidental_, but not an _accident_. But then, I don't think I'd use _bump_ for an _accident_ either.

Comment: @jimsug: Actually, I wouldn't normally use *bump* either. It was only in the answer because I googled **synonym shunt prang** and cut&pasted it from bthe first result. On reflection, I think only people older than *me* are really likely to use the term like this, so I think I'll remove it as "no longer relevant".

Answer (score 1):

Two Different perspectives for you.

I crashed my car - only my car had been involved in the accident (edit- most probably only my car, as otherwise, we would use one of the below sentences, except in the case of omitting what exactly you hit, in this case, you would most likely be subjected to further questioning and then would explain what exactly you had hit, thus see options below first)

I crashed my car into another car/ I hit a car/ I collided with a car - my car (or vehicle) and another had been involved.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think so; _crash_ doesn't require an object, so you can say _I crashed my car_ even if you hit another car, especially if you don't want to mention this fact.

Comment: Yes, but without adding the specific object, we cannot be sure of what? It could be a post/tree/deer. Avoiding it in the first sentence would only lead to further interest/questioning anyway, this wouldn't be normal if you'd hit another car. However I had a car crash, now that would be more probable of further cars involved.

Comment: Yep - you can't be sure, which means that you can't rule out a collision with another car - it neither confirms nor denies this. And if, say, you wanted to avoid mentioning that you hit another car, then you could say this. And I don't know what you mean when you say it wouldn't be normal - context is everything, and if you have an unusual enough context, you can make anything normal.

Comment: A ruling out was no intention here, though had you hit another car, in the most part you would refer to the car you hit rather than your own.... I'm using only the context here.

Comment: "A ruling out was no intention here" But your post: "only my car had been involved in the accident". Seems like ruling out to me - may I suggest you edit your answer to clarify when this would be the case, then?

Comment: I'm using a natural language flow here, not trying to overcomplicate, however I will edit it for your satisfaction.